# I just figured out what flag weight is, can you guys create some spam for me to flag?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight

I was reading up on flag weights today, and figured it is going to be pretty hard to get a high rating because we don't get very much spam(at least that I see).  I'd appreciate it if you guys could create some spam so I can bump up to the 749 flag weight level.

Comment: Note: I understand if you mark this as spam

Comment: In this "figuring out", did you notice the part where you need [more than 500 correct flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97890/how-many-flags-to-reach-750-flag-weight/103161#103161) to reach that weight?

Answer (score 13):

No, we can't do that.

In order to accomplish this, it would require a money transfer from Nigeria. Which is troublesome, you see, because of all the V1AGR4. And the jeans. The *religious* jeans. They interact, you see. Very problematic, that.

Hoping this finds you in good health, and thoroughly confused,
-Prince Shog of Nine

Answer (score 2):

Oh, come on...

We have already worked hard to fill the site with missspellings, grammaticy errors missing punctuation and its not like we've got *all* the apostrophes right. not all of us have used shift key, SOME MORE THAN OTHERS though. Sometimes, accidentally, questions bad title?

But I don't see you having the Copy Editor badge yet...

Comment: I haven't really singled out badges yet to get, i'll have to look into that one